# Names from an imported package are shown, but crossed out

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xerces

I imported the `xercesImpl.jar` into my Android project.

It seems to recognize it when I use it (i.e. lists all available methods), but the names are crossed out. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Because the class or its methods are [`@Deprecated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html).

> The `@Deprecated` annotation indicates that the marked element is *deprecated* and should no longer be used. The compiler generates a warning whenever a program uses a method, class, or field with the @Deprecated annotation. When an element is deprecated, it should also be documented using the Javadoc `@deprecated` tag, as shown in the following example. The use of the "@" symbol in both Javadoc comments and in annotations is not coincidental—they are related conceptually. Also, note that the Javadoc tag starts with a lowercase "d" and the annotation starts with an uppercase "D".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't use these elements anymore, or I should add the @SuppressWarnings annotation?

Comment: In this particular case, you probably shouldn't be directly referencing classes/methods from `xercesImpl.jar` in your project. Use the standard APIs that Xerces provides an implementation of - to wit, JAXP. If you don't already have such a JAR in your classpath, `xml-apis.jar` should provide what you need.

Comment: I received the following error using xml-apis.jar "[2011-12-02 11:31:44 - GeneralGUI7] Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library."